# Python regex does not match

Tags: python, regex, string

```
import re
str2='hello: acb cross'
reg = re.compile('hello: (a*) cross')
m = reg.search(str2)
print m
if m:
   nat= m.group(0)
   print(nat)
```

In the above snippet i was expecting output to be 'hello: acb cross' and if I do group(1) it should have been 'acb'. But I did not get any. print m returns None. Could anyone please let me know the reason it does not work.

However if I try something like this, it works:

```
import re
str1 = "carter notes: dependent on stems"
r = re.compile('carter notes:(.*)stems')
m = r.search(str1)
if m:
   lx = m.group(1)
   #print(m.group(0))
   print(lx)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
str2='hello: acb cross'
reg = re.compile('hello: (a.*?) cross')
```

Comment: thanks ATOzTOA. It worked. I tried reg = re.compile('hello: (a.*) cross') and it works too.. no need of '?'.

Comment: `?` makes the regex less 'greedy', the search matches least number of characters as opposed to maximum number of characters when '?' is not used.

Answer (score 2):

`a*` means "any number of `a`s".

`.*` means "any number of (any single character)".

You meant "an `a`, followed by any number of (any single character)"; that is `a.*`.

Comment: More likely than not, the intention is `.*?`

Comment: a* means 0 or more 'a's in that case isn't acb to match that? It has 1 'a'

Comment: Yes, but after matching 1 `a`, the next thing in the data is `cb`, which does not match ` cross`.

Comment: And, for what it's worth, "any number of" above includes zero. Using the "one or more of) (.+), or per Jon Clements, (.+?) is often closer to what people have in mind.